# Grunt Uglify get sum of space saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have grunt-contrib-uglify minifying a bunch of js files for me, and thought it would be really neat if it could sum up the difference in file sizes before and after minification.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple method would be to write your own task that used the [nodejs file system library](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to list out the sizes of the files you want to compare using `fs.Stats`. A more complex option would be to log both the pre and post sizes to a file with a timestamp so that they can be tracked and graphed.

Or go to npmjs.org and grab an existing project to use as the base to build on: [grunt-size-report](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-size-report)

## grunt-size-report

Modify your `Gruntfile.js` to add a section for `size_report`:

```
size_report: {
    your_target: {
        files: {
            list: ['path/to/*.html', 'path/to/images/*.jpg']
        },
    },
},
```

and if you add the `size_report` call into your list of build commands you'll get:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~
Size report
~~~~~~~~~~~

Filename                      Size          %
---------------------------------------------
test/testfiles/test4.txt     9.6 KiB    46.8%
test/testfiles/test1.txt     7.0 KiB    34.0%
test/testfiles/test2.txt     3.5 KiB    17.0%
test/testfiles/test3.txt     447 B       2.1%
=============================================
Total:                      20.5 KiB
```

This report isn't showing % space saved, but if you run it with two separate subtasks on your `/app` and then your `/dist` folders you can perform the comparison manually yourself.